# When will the Python 2.7.9 upgrades be available from apt-get for 14.04LTS?

Tags: apt

The ssl related fixes in that are critical to network security.

Answer (score 5):

The upstream version of Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 14.04 will always be 2.7.6. However, the distribution version (`8` in `2.7.6-8`) will change. Instead of looking for Python 2.7.9, check the [changelogs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/python2.7) to see if the fixes have been backported. Since 2.7.9 will be part of Ubuntu 15.04, I'd expect an update around the time [14.04.2 releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DraftReleaseSchedule), if ever. The corresponding [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/1401322) is as yet unassigned.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid regressions, it has been decided that it won't be backported

http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-9365.html

Answer (score 0):

It is still in progress,not abandoned and no date set. Check [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/1401322) for details

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/530400)

Comment: In this case, the answer to "when?" is: "still in progress. not abandoned, no date set, details (and discussion) on the thread provided."

Comment: Since the same bug is linked in my answer from over a year ago, what's new in this answer?